# How to get thumbnail of images from USB storage device on Android device?

Tags: android, android-image, android-file, android-usb

If USB storage is connected to android device, how can I get thumbnails from images in drive without actually copying image from drive to device?

Comment: Have you read: https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html#load-bitmap

Comment: @Sam, Yes. Problem here is that android doesn't detect usb as sd card and we cannot get physical path so cannot list files otherwise I would have used bitmap apis. So main problem here is how to get physical path of images(files in general) on usb pen drive.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201169/how-app-can-access-files-on-usb-otg-storages-in-android-6-0-api-level-23-witho

Comment: Its related, but answer suggests it is not possible which is not true. There are apps which are able to do. For example ES File Explorer shows thumbnails of images without using storage access framework.

Comment: See comments in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26485138/android-usb-host-read-write-a-file-in-usb-device-otg